# is there a way to zoom in the screen?

Tags: actionscript-3

In a certain point when you want to see things closer, can you zoom in the whole screen without changing the games' levels and items' size and scale?

In an swf file, you can right click to zoom in, but I want the same feature for the game using code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with the `scaleX`and `scaleY` properties of the `DisplayObject`, which holds your graphic elements.
Assumed,`holder` contains your stuff:

```
holder.scaleX = holder.scaleY = 2;
```

will scale the holder and all its children to double size.

Comment: Or you can just scale the main timeline / document root.  `root.scaleX = root.scaleY = 2;`